# Hive : casting array<string> to array<int> in query

Tags: arrays, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have two tables :

```
create table a (
`1` array<string>);

create table b (
`1` array<int>);
```

and I want to put the table a in table b (table b is empty) :

```
insert into table b
select * from a;
```

when doing so I get the following error :

```
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10044]: Line 1:18 Cannot insert into
target table because column number/types are different 'b': Cannot
convert column 0 from array<string> to array<int>.
```

whereas I would not get this error if the fields were only of types `string` and `int`.

Is there a way to do the cast with arrays ?

Answer (score 3):

Re-assemble array using `explode()` and `collect_list()`.

Initial String array example:

```
hive> select array('1','2','3') string_array;
OK
string_array
["1","2","3"]
Time taken: 1.109 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

Convert array:

```
hive> select collect_list(cast(array_element as int)) int_array --cast and collect array
       from( select explode(string_array) array_element         --explode array
               from (select array('1','2','3') string_array     --initial array
                    )s 
           )s;
```

Result:

```
OK
int_array
[1,2,3]
Time taken: 44.668 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

And if you want to add more columns in your insert+select query then use 
`lateral view [outer]`:

```
select col1, col2, collect_list(cast(array_element as int)) int_array
 from
(
select col1, col2 , array_element         
  from table
       lateral view outer explode(string_array) a as array_element         
)s
group by col1, col2
;
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll try it!

Comment: `select col1, col2, collect_list(cast(array_element as int)) int_array
 from
(
select col1, col2 , array_element         
  from table
       lateral view outer explode(string_array) a as array_element         
)s
group by col1, col2
;```  solve my problem

Comment: `select col1, col2, collect_list(cast(array_element as int)) int_array from ( select col1, col2 , array_element from table lateral view outer explode(string_array) a as array_element )s group by col1, col2` works. but I have a question that how the array element is kept the same order with the original array?

Comment: @ningyuwhut  In this example the order is not preserved (not guarantied). To have the same order use posexplode instead of explode to get position and use distribute by col1, col2  sort by position in the inner subquery. , like in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61936243/2700344

Answer (score 3):

**Brickhouse jar will do this  a lot faster than casting them and collecting it back as a list . Add this jar to a hdfs location.

[Use the link below to download the brick house jar](https://jar-download.com/artifacts/com.klout/brickhouse/0.5.5/source-code/brickhouse/udf/collect/CastArrayUDF.java)**

```
add jar hdfs://hadoop-/pathtojar/brickhouse-0.7.1.jar;   
create temporary function cast_array as 'brickhouse.udf.collect.CastArrayUDF';   
select cast_array(columns, 'int') AS columname from table;  
select cast_array(columns, 'string') AS columname from table
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to do the cast with arrays ?

Not easily. You can manually cast the arrays if you know their size, but if not you might need to use structs. See my answer to [this similar question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47785271/convert-string-to-arrayint-in-hive/52998490#52998490)

---

Also: I cannot downvote the other answer, but it fails for nested selects with more than one array.

Instead of casting array elements and reconstructing the original arrays, it casts and then combines all elements into a single array. Example:

```
hive> select id, my_array from array_table limit 3;
OK
10023307    ["0.20296966","0.17753501","-0.03543373"]
100308007   ["0.16155224","0.1945944","0.09167781"]
100384207   ["0.025892768","0.023214806","-0.003712816"]

hive> select
    >     collect_list(cast(array_element as double)) int_array
    > from (
    >     select
    >         explode(my_array) array_element
    >     from (
    >         select
    >             my_array
    >         from array_table limit 3
    >     ) X
    > ) s;
OK
[0.20296966,0.17753501,-0.03543373,0.16155224,0.1945944,0.09167781,0.025892768,0.023214806,-0.003712816]
```