# Hive array of string into array of int

Tags: hive, hiveql

In Hive I have a table with a column as string datatype and it contains set of numbers say marks. So I want to apply some arithmetic operations like addition, so I used split command and it returns array. Bt I can't apply addition to the array I think I need to convert into array to apply any arithmetic operations. I used command followed

```
select sum(a) from (select split(marks, ':') as a from tbl) b;
```

And I tried to cast it into array also bt not working giving some error. I tried following commands

```
select sum(a) from (select cast(split(marks, ':') as a array<int>) from table) b;
select sum(a) from (select cast(b) as array<int> from (select split(marks, ':') as b from tbl) c) d;
```

Please suggest me the solution for this.. And also how to cast array to array

Comment: Could you please provide your input sample? That way it'll be easy to help you

Comment: Marks
45:52:56:74
85:65:63:42
63:52:43:68

Marks column as string datatype and table name is tbl

Comment: You can do CAST(Split(marks,':')[0] AS bigint),CAST(Split(marks,':')[1] AS bigint),CAST(Split(marks,':')[2] AS bigint),CAST(Split(marks,':')[3] AS bigint)

Comment: Answered the same: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50333654/2700344

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
select sum(cast(a as int)) from TableName;
```

Comment: It won't work I think it will give classCastException because a is an array<string> so we can't cast into int..

Comment: You can use this: select a, sum(cast(a as int)) as sum_of_marks from TableName lateral view explode (split(marks,':')) t1 AS a

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this, hope this helps

```
Select 
 sum(a), 
 sum(b), 
 sum(c), 
 sum(d)
From
(Select
  CAST(Split(marks,':')[0] AS bigint) AS a, 
  CAST(Split(marks,':')[1] AS bigint) AS b,
  CAST(Split(marks,':')[2] AS bigint) AS c, 
  CAST(Split(marks,':')[3] AS bigint) AS d
From
Table) split_data
Group by <some column>
```